# What software do I need for the manager versus the agent

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to design a system to communicate between a manager computer and a single embedded agent using Net-snmp.

One thing that does not seem to be answered clearly is the difference in base software that you need on the manager versus the agent computers.

On most tutorials they seem to install "snmp" on both the agent and the manager and additionally download "snmpd" on the agent.

My current understanding is you need the base "snmp" on the manager, and you need "snmpd" on the agent. But my confusion comes from whether you need to install "snmp" on the agent. It seems like you would bloat the agent with a lot of manager specific software.

I understand this would make sense for if you want to query data locally in the agent, but in the situation you want to reduce the agent software size for an embedded system do you need to install "snmp" on it, and if you do is there any way to remove manager specific files?

Thanks!

Edit: Just a little bit more info to better specify my question or where I am having confusion. On the faq, it has things like including ""--enable-mini-agent" when compiling snmp for the agent, which specifies you need to install "snmp" for the agent. But there was also a separate tutorial that did not include "snmp" on the agent which is why I am confused at whether you would need "snmp" on the agent and if you do not then what benefit it has over not including it. Thanks.

Comment: Edit the question to include extra information. Don't misuse comments.

Comment: It is too broad to discuss such using Net-SNMP as an example, as it ships as a bundle. If you develop your own agent and manager, they can be completely separate pieces and running on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Lex, the bit "it ships as a bundle" was the bit I was missing as this was not mentioned anywhere, so for someone new this "obvious once you know it" piece of information not being mentioned explicitly on the site was important for my overall understanding.

Basically my overall confusion on thinking the net-snmp source package was not a bundle for the agent and manager came from this tutorial I followed: https://www.maketecheasier.com/net-snmp-part-1/, as it was the only tutorial that got net-snmp to work correctly. My confusion was that he was installing the bundled net-snmp package from the source, but was also installing a seperate snmp daemon via "sudo apt-get install snmpd". I was assuming therefore that you needed to install snmpd separate to get the daemon working.

The tutorial did not mention that snmpd is actually already included in the source and you do not need to do the "sudo apt-get install snmpd" command for snmpd to work as you are just doing a redundant download and install.